# jQuery toggleClass - can't animate or give it a transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having a small issue with my code. I have an element that when the page scrolls it will appear. However, I cannot get it to "appear" in a smoother way. I have tried CSS transitions and attempted fadeIn  but neither work. It always just "jumps" in, I cannot get it to ease in.

Here is the code:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    $('.navbar').toggleClass('visible', $(document).scrollTop() > 40);
});
```

So it appears just fine, but I can't figure out how to animate adding the class name.

This is the CSS btw:

```
.navbar {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.navbar.visible {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`visibility` can't be animated with CSS transitions.

But you can do :

```
.navbar {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease; // Feel free to use prefixes.
}

.navbar.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

CSS transition / animations is surely the best way to animate something in 2014. You should avoid fadeToggle() and others jQuery animation methods.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think this one worked the best!

Comment: You did 50% of the job considering CSS animations would be a better choice than JS animations.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using toggleClass, use fadeToggle. it will do everything for u as far as CSS..

give it a try, just fadeToggle();

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of your code with correct css transition. You cannot animate visibility, but you can play with position and opacity.

http://jsfiddle.net/xZ6fm/

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: -100px;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    padding: 12px;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #ccc;
}

.navbar.visible {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.3s linear, opacity 0.7s linear;
    -moz-transition: top 0.3s linear, opacity 0.7s linear;
    transition: top 0.3s linear, opacity 0.7s linear;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As indicated in the other answer, fadeToggle() will get the work done for you. And frankly, it's probably the easiest way to accomplish such an effect.

CSS transitions require the transition property. Place this block of code in each of your CSS declarations:

```
transition: visibility .25s linear;
-webkit-transition: visibility .25s linear;
-moz-transition: visibility .25s linear;
-o-transition: visibility .25s linear;
```

If you have difficulties with visibility, try using opacity instead.